# How to handle a forEach loop that returns early based on an enum except for one path in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

We have an API service call that returns a bunch of validation messages. In each message there is a string that contains an error code.

Our implementation converts the validation string into an enum value and then we process the enumeration as there are some error code we just don't care about.

The question becomes, how to handle the loop of messages in a Kotlin way:

```kotlin
response.validationErrors?.forEach {
    val mediaFailure = decodeValidationMessage(it.message)

    if (mediaFailure != MediaFailure.Unknown) {
        return when (mediaFailure) {
            MediaFailure.Encrypted -> DomainResponse(ErrorReasonCode.ERR_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTED)
            MediaFailure.NotSupported -> Response.validationFailed()
            MediaFailure.InternalError -> Response.serviceFailed()
            else -> throw NotImplementedError()
        }
    }
}
```

Here we loop through all the messages, then once the message error is not "Unknown" it returns the necessary response to the caller.

However, IntelliJ wants the `else` path, even though the `if` prevents that from happening.

Is there a proper Kotlin way of implementing this kind of loop?

Comment: What do you want to return when all `mediaFailure`s are `MediaFailure.Unknown`? (Because this is theoretically possible)

Comment: `Response.serviceFailed()` is the default return as there is a earlier catch for success and we only process this loop when the service indicates there is an error - also, if something went wrong that isn't a validation error (`validationErrors is null`) that return `serviceFailed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to return a response for the first `mediaFailure` which is not `MediaFailure.Unknown` and you don't want that `throw NotImplementedError()` part in your function.
One way to fix this is to remove the `if` condition and continue the `forEach` loop when `MediaFailure.Unknown` is found.

```kotlin
response.validationErrors?.forEach {
    val mediaFailure = decodeValidationMessage(it.message)

    return when (mediaFailure) {
        MediaFailure.Encrypted -> DomainResponse(ErrorReasonCode.ERR_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTED)
        MediaFailure.NotSupported -> Response.validationFailed()
        MediaFailure.InternalError -> Response.serviceFailed()
        MediaFailure.Unknown -> return@forEach // continue the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of the many cases when it pays to step back from the code a bit and try to look at the big picture. To ask “What's the ultimate goal here? What am I trying to achieve with this code?”

(In traditional, lower-level languages, almost anything you want to do with a list or array requires a loop, so you get into the habit of reaching for a `for` or `while` without thinking. But there are often alternative approaches in Kotlin that can be more concise, clearer, and harder to get wrong. They tend to be more about *what* you're trying to achieve, rather than *how*.)

In this case, it looks you want to find the *first* item which decodes to give a known type (i.e. not `MediaFailure.Unknown`), and return a value derived from that.

So here's an attempt to code *that*:

```
val message = response.validationErrors?.asSequence()
    ?.map{ decodeValidationMessage(it.message) }
    ?.firstOrNull{ it != MediaFailure.Unknown }

return when (message) {
    MediaFailure.Encrypted -> DomainResponse(ErrorReasonCode.ERR_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTED)
    MediaFailure.NotSupported -> Response.validationFailed()
    MediaFailure.InternalError, null -> Response.serviceFailed()
    else -> throw NotImplementedError()
}
```

This is still fairly similar to your code, and it's about as efficient. (Thanks to the `asSequence()`, it doesn't decode any more messages than it needs to.) But the `firstOrNull()` makes clear what you're looking for; and it's obvious that you go on to process only that one message — a fact which is rather lost in the original version.

(If there are *no* valid messages, `message` will be null and so this will return `serviceFailed()`, as per comments.)

There are of course many ways to skin a cat, and I can think of several variations. (It's often a worthwhile exercise to come up with some — if nothing else, it gives you more confidence in the version you end up with!) Try to pick whichever seems clearest, simplest, and best matches the big picture of what you're doing; that tends to work out best in the long run.

Comment: Nice - thanks :+1: - some solid advice there :)